# jQuery Flip on hover - using flag to keep flip from running repeatedly on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, transform, flags, flip

I'm trying to use the script from http://lab.smashup.it/flip/ because in my testing it is the most reliable across browsers/OSs.  pure CSS 3D transform only works on FF/Chrome by my testing.

anywho, the script appears to be intended for clicks and I'm trying to implement it by hover.

what I want is hover (or maybe mouseenter) over DIV "A" flips that for DIV "B".  then, on hover off (or mouseleave) it flips back to original DIV "A".  that should work forever, hover="flip to B" and hover-off="flip back to A". eventually, there will be a click behavior on "B" but that shouldn't effect what's going on here if the hover state is working properly.

I have it working through one cycle, hover flips DIV A to DIV B.  when hover off, DIV B flips back to DIV A.  the problem is that it doesn't work a second time.  a "flag" I've created to keep the flip function from flipping continuously on hover (not stopping on B) starts at 0, then gets set to 1 after the first hover spin.  on mouseout it's supposed to reset that flag to 0 and it appears to be in console.log, but when I hover over DIV A a second time, the console.log says it's set to 1 still , and so that hover doesn't work a second/third/etc time.  it might just be an issue with the way I've set up my flags, I dunno...

here's a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypdvrdu9/1/

here's my CSS:

```
#flipbox-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 390px;   
    height: 265px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#flipbox-over {
    position: absolute; 
    z-index: 2;
    width: 390px;   
    height: 245px;
    /* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); */
}
#flipbox-front {
    width: 390px;   
    height: 265px;  
    color: #fff;
    background: green;
}
#flipbox-back {
    display: none;
    width: 390px;   
    height: 265px;  
    color: #fff;
    background: red;
}
```

here's the HTML:

```
<div id="flipbox-wrapper">
    <div id="flipbox-over"></div>
    <div id="flipbox-front">
        <img src="thumb-03.png"/>
        front
    </div>
    <div id="flipbox-back">
        <img src="thumb-04.png"/>
        back
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's my custom JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

            flipFlag = 0;
            $('#flipbox-over').hover(function() {
                    console.log('mouseenter flipFlag: ' + flipFlag);
                if (flipFlag == 0) {
                    $('#flipbox-front').flip({
                        direction: 'lr',
                        color: 'red',
                        content: $('#flipbox-back'),
                        onEnd: function(){
                            // end
                            flipFlag = 1;
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
              function() {
                // on mouseout function
                if (flipFlag == 1) {
                    $('#flipbox-front').revertFlip();
                    flipFlag = 0;
                }
                    console.log('mouseout flipFlag: ' + flipFlag);
                flipFlag = 0;
            });     

        });
```

[also requires jQuery and jQuery UI]

here's the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypdvrdu9/1/

any and all help appreciated.  I'm hoping this is a simple one that won't eat up too much of anyone's time.  much thanks!

Comment: can you share the fiddle

Comment: ok, here's a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypdvrdu9/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypdvrdu9/2/ instead of `#flipbox-over` I used     `#flipbox-front` and `#flipbox-back` thus the resulting js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    flipFlag = 0;
    $('#flipbox-front, #flipbox-back').hover(function () {
        console.log('mouseenter flipFlag: ' + flipFlag);
        if (flipFlag == 0) {
            $('#flipbox-front').flip({
                direction: 'lr',
                color: 'red',
                content: $('#flipbox-back'),
                onEnd: function () {
                    // end
                    flipFlag = 1;
                }
            });
        }
    },
        function () {
            // on mouseout function
            if (flipFlag == 1) {
                $('#flipbox-front').revertFlip();
                flipFlag = 0;
            }
            console.log('mouseout flipFlag: ' + flipFlag);
            flipFlag = 0;
        });
});
```

**Update:** A better option would be something like in: http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/yzahJ that uses [tweenLite](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenLite/) and [tweenmax](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/) that are more up-to-date libraries by http://greensock.com

Comment: this looks like it works!  thank you so much.  yeah, the "over" DIV felt unnecessary, but I thought it might be helpful to separate what selector the hover relied on from the two flipping DIVs themselves.

Comment: Yes temporarily it gives you what you want but I can suggest some other thing that doesnt have shortcomings of this old library... may you please take a look at : http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/yzahJ A more up-to-date library by http://greensock.com

Comment: TweenMax looks great, but it doesn't appear to work on IE, even IE11.  I'm looking at their site at http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/ and can't find info on IE

Comment: That's right I haven't realized that it flips into an incorrect content.. After a little search: I have found this discussion: http://greensock.com/forums/topic/9100-card-flip-in-ie/ that pointsto this pen: http://codepen.io/rhernando/pen/vjGxH that I have tested on IE 11 and that it works. Please check if that works for you too.

Comment: Nice. I thought I had looked all over and couldn't find related IE info on greensock, or the web. This seems to do the trick!!! Plus, the flip animation is smoother too.  The previous one kind of snapped/jerked just as it settled into the end of the animation, and this one is smooth all around with my fully built out "cards".  I was just about to turn it over, without IE, and you followed through and got back to me in the nick of time.  Thank you so much.